# c++ copy constructor, after copy random value

Tags: c++

I also have some errors with copy constructor that I cant figure out, but the main question at the moment is brought out in my test programs comments. Why is the second print out so big number, and not three? Thank in advance for your help.

```
template<class T>
class Array {
    private:
        T *cont;
        unsigned int size;

    public:

    Array()=default;


    T& elementAt(unsigned int i)
    {
    return cont[i]; 
    }


    Array( const Array &a ) 
    {
    cont = new int[ size ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        cont[ i ] = a.cont[ i ];
    }


    Array& operator = (const Array& a)
    {
    int i,min_size;
    if(size < a.size)
        min_size = size;
    else
        min_size = a.size;
    for(i=0; i<min_size; i++)
        cont[i] = a.cont[i];
    return (*this);
    }


    void addElement(T element) {
        T *new_cont = new T[size + 1], *old_cont = cont;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            new_cont[i] = old_cont[i];
        }

        new_cont[size] = element;
        size++;

        cont = new_cont;
        delete old_cont;
    }


    unsigned int getSize() const
    {
    return size;
    }


    ~Array()
    {
    delete [] cont;
    }



};
```

And this part of my test program:

```
Array<int> numbers;             
    numbers.addElement (5);         
    numbers.addElement (11);        
    numbers.addElement (3);
        cout << numbers.getSize()<<endl;  // Here I get output: 3
    cout<< numbers.elementAt(1)<<endl; // output: 11
        MyArray<int> copy2;
    copy2 = numbers;    
        cout << copy2.getSize()<<endl;  //  WHY is output: 2686697, in here? Why isn' t it 3.
    cout<< copy2.elementAt(1)<<endl; // output: 11
```

Comment: Most probably `cont = new int[ size ];` should be `cont = new int[ a.size ];` in your copy constructor.

Comment: There's at least one problem in your code: at `Array( const Array &a )` you should add `size = a.size;` at the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong `size` to allocate memory in the copy constructor.

```
Array( const Array &a ) 
{
  // Get the size from the copy first. Without it, size is an unitialized
  // value, which will lead to undefined behavior.
  size = a.size;
  cont = new int[ size ];

  for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    cont[ i ] = a.cont[ i ];
}
```

The other problem that I see is the implementation of the default constructor. The default constructor can be used in two ways:

```
Array<int> numbers;
```

or

```
Array<int> numbers = Array<int>();
```

The former will result in uninitialized data while the latter will result in properly initialized data with your implementation. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new).

You can change the default constructor to:

```
Array() : size(0), cont(NULL) {}
```

to make your code work identically in either way of constructing the object.

The third problem is the `operator=` function. It does not perform a true assignment. It only stores the minimum number of elements from the two objects. Try this:

```
   Array& operator = (const Array& a)
   {
      // Make statements like 'a = a;' a noop.
      if ( this != &a )
      {
         // If the size of the LHS is larger than or equal to the size
         // of the RHS, the LHS has enough memory to store the data
         // from the RHS.
         if ( this->size >= a.size )
         {
            this->size = a.size;
            for(int i=0; i<a.size; i++)
               cont[i] = a.cont[i];
         }
         else
         {
            // The size of the LHS is smaller than the size of the RHS,
            // It does not have enough memory to store the data from
            // the RHS. Dellocate old memory. Allocate new memory.
            // Then copy the data.
            this->size = a.size;
            delete [] cont;
            cont = new int[this->size];
            for(int i=0; i<a.size; i++)
               cont[i] = a.cont[i];

         }
      }
      return (*this);
   }
```

Comment: Somehow it is still giving the same random size. I think that maybe I was not using copy constructor in my testing program. So I tried to use line:  Array<int> copy = numbers;   it compiles, but when I run the program it crashes, and does not give any error.

Comment: @user3328230 I updated my answer to address another problematic piece of code. Hopefully that will solver your problems.

Comment: It is probably my own fault, but I still can't get it to work properly. I think your version of the copy constructor is correct, but my:  Array& operator = (const Array& a)  has an error maybe. Could I be wright ? I saw that somebody used a similar line in his program: Array<int> copy = numbers; I intend to make copy named "copy" of array named "numbers". So I am not allowed to use it like that? It seemed to work for him.

Answer (score 1):

At the time you call your copy constructor, the `size` member is uninitialized. You probably meant

```
 size = a.size; // Initialize size member also, it's not done automagically
 cont = new int[ size ];
```

in your copy constructor.

Comment: Better yet: add `size = a.size;` at the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You should get size from object a

```
Array( const Array &a ) 
{
    cont = new int[ a.size ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < a.size; i++ )
        cont[ i ] = a.cont[ i ];
}
```

Comment: Better yet: add `size = a.size;` at the first line.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I have one further question. cont = new int[ a.size ]; should I maybe use some other type than int if I want my class to be template. I am sorry if this is stupid question. Maybe cont = new T[a.size] ?

Comment: Yes for templates you should use T like:
cont = new T[ a.size ];

Comment: Somehow it is still giving the same random size. I think that maybe I was not using copy constructor in my testing program. Instead maybe this (Array& operator = (const Array& a))  So I tried to use line to use copy constructor: Array<int> copy = numbers; it compiles, but when I run the program it crashes, and does not give any error.